# How to format a reply as a code snippet when responding to a bitbucket comment via slack?

Tags: bitbucket, slack-commands

I am trying to reply to a comment, on a PR, on bitbucket with a code snippet instead of plain text, from the associated slack channel.

Comment: I don't think this question is correct on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is quite straightforward. Put the code lines in between these(```). As StackOverflow is following the same thing, I have to apply some trick:

Let ``` = AAA. Then,

AAA

This is your code.
Place your code here.

AAA

This will be the output:

```
This is your code. Place your code here.
```

Answer (score 7):

use 3 '`' chars to make a code block. you can also give a language syntax hint by adding the name of the language after the 3 ticks.

i.e.

````
```javascript
var x = 0;
```
````

which looks like

```js
var x = 0;
```

or you can do inline code using a single '`'.

i.e.

```
Your variable `VAR_NAME` is never initialized
```

which looks like this

Your variable `VAR_NAME` is never initialized

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Atlassian markdown syntax guide:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/markdown-syntax-guide-776639995.html

In to format your comment as a code block you indent it by 4 spaces.